# Как получить данные из нескольких таблиц с похожими именами по маске?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть более 10 таблиц с одинаковой структурой и похожими названиями.

Нужно выбрать одним запросом (или небольшим количеством запросов) из всех таблиц данные по одному условию не перечисляя таблицы.

Например table_a, table_b и table_c - содержат id и имя.

Как сформировать запрос типа SELECT * FROM table_(.*) WHERE id = 13 чтоб получить
table_a.name, table_b.name, table_c.name которые в php можно получить массивом и перебрать?

Comment: joinы и unionы отменили?

Comment: нет не отменили, но нет примеров использования их для запросов к таблицам с неизвестным названием и без указания их вручную

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант, кажется, это использовать [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html). Обойдите массив названий таблиц и сгенерируйте запросы, объедените их с помощью union.

```
<?php

$tables = [
    'table_a',
    'table_b',
    'table_c',
];
$queries = [];
foreach ($tables as $tableName) {
    $queries[] = '
        select
            `id`,
            `name`,
            "' . $tableName . '" as `tableName`
        from `' . $tableName . '`
        where id = 13
    ';
}

$sql = implode(' union ', $queries);
```

Только обратите внимание, имена таблиц и параметры запроса (если они у вас будут динамические) надо экранировать. Мой пример просто демонстрирует принцип, доработайте его, если будете использовать.

Comment: Об этом способе я и сам подумал - не совсем то что нужно. Хочу понять как можно объединить именно в sql запросе, а так же не перечисляя таблицы вручную - у меня их сейчас 68 и следить за появлением новых созданных скажем через админку каждый раз править файлы, хранить пары где-то в бд тоже не вариант - таблицы созданы и уверен что можно как-то получить их по шаблону.

Comment: @RoboMobo делайте запрос в БД на получение всех таблиц, вам вернется массив, выбирайте необходимые вам таблицы и генерируйте запрос, в чем проблема?

Comment: нужен именно запрос sql без php, он не столько нужен сколько хочется понять в образовательных целях как сделать любой запрос к таблицам по шаблону для образовательных целей. в гугл не посылайте - там нет ответа, а вопросы есть.

Comment: @RoboMobo MySQL не поддерживает wildcard'ы имён таблиц. Но вы можете создать хранимку, которая делает тоже самое, что и php-скрипт.